# Laravel Mix minify js files from sub folders

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

Within my project I have javascript file for each page, it just helps me manage it easier like that and I would prefer not to merge it into singular file.

I am trying to use laravel webpack mix to minify my javascript files, my resource folder structure looks something like this:

```
Resources/
  js/
    backoffice/
      payments/
        index.js
      users/
        index.js
        details.js
      common.js
```

I want the same structure to be kept in my public folder only minified, I want it to look something like this:

```
Public/
  assets/
    js/
      backoffice/
        payments/
          index.min.js
        users/
          index.min.js
          details.min.js
        common.min.js
```

Unfortunately when I am trying to use:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/**/*.js', 'public/assets/js/');
```

Only common.js file is getting minified and has been put in correct place. Have anyone had this issue before and been able to minify files separately like this and if you did it how did you achieved it?

Thanks for all your help!
Eddie

Comment: if you want all file in separate folder then you have to use `mix.js` for each file as a separate entry. check this https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/mixjs.md#usage

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/menu.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/cart.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Add each file, then just use the second parameter for where you want the file to be stored.